a deleted node in a list stays in the list
I making a func(checking what should be deleted in a list. i have current and pre and todeleted pointers.
cur runs. pre runs after him, and we reach a problamatic node we deleted it whit todelet(he points in cur location and cur point to the next ).
problem . after deletion cur becoms null ,and i dont know why(even if the list isnt null)
void RemuveRepitingPos(List* lst, chessboard* checkBoard) {
    ListNode* cur = lst->head;
   // ListNode* toDelete = NULL;
    ListNode* pre=NULL;
  
    while (cur!=NULL) {
        printf("checking pos (%c,%c): ", cur->pos[0], cur->pos[1]);
        if ((*checkBoard)[cur->pos[0]-'A'][cur->pos[1]-'1'] == 1) {
            printf("Pos invalid\n");
            ListNode* toDelete = cur;
            cur = cur->next;
            deletNodeFromMidList(toDelete, pre, lst);
           if (!lst->head) {
    if (!cur)
        printf("cur is null why?\n");
    else
        printf("new cur is pos letter is: %c\n", cur->pos[0]);
}
        else {
            printf("Pos valide\n");
            pre = cur;
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    }
}
void deletNodeFromMidList(ListNode* deleted, ListNode* pre, list* lst) {
 
   if (pre == NULL) {//you remuve head
        lst->head = deleted->next;
    }
    else if (deleted==lst->tail)//remuve tail
    {
        lst->tail = pre;
    }
    else//mid list
    {
        pre->next = deleted->next;
    }
    free(deleted);
    
}

on printing the list after change:
void printL(List lst) {
    ListNode* runner = lst.head;
    printf("list printing start :\n");
    while (runner != NULL) {
        printf("(%c,%c)", runner->pos[0], runner->pos[1]);
        runner = runner->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

i found this(as an exmple) :list printing start :
(D,3)(▌,▌)
after that the pogram collaps .
and yes i checked cur is null after the deletion ,
checking on here,prints alot,chat,reading on pointers
edit here is the print :
list printing start :
(D,3)(C,4)
checking pos (D,3): Pos valide
checking pos (C,4): Pos invalid
cur is null why?
after remuval
list printing start :
(D,3)(▌,▌)

Edit the question to provide a [mre].

After deleting last node you aren't changing pre->next to NULL

@stark what do you meant by that

@EricPostpischil sorry here i wrote what the dubging wrote

It is time to learn how to use the debugger https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/april/article2.php

Get out a paper and pencil, draw your list (boxes and arrows), then follow your code while updating the arrows to see what it does. When playing with linked lists, always do this.

You use list as the list type some places and List as the list type other places.  How does it compile?

After lst->tail = pre what does pre->next point to?

@stark ok wow .thats that's fixed crushes ..its still does the cur is null why ! But like the pogram works  think... But im 5 minutes in and its still calculating..well thats something i will need to see tomorrow thanks for the halp

I suggest you rewrite the question (instead of telling us a story of what happen write a failing test case in code).  As is we have to assemble snippets, write what is missing to try to reproduce the issue.  RemuveRepitingPos() is missing a closing } so the code you post never ran.

You have 4 types ListNode, list, List and chessboard we don't know anything about.

RemuveRepitingPos() 2nd argument is a chessboard* checkBoard which you deference with (*checkBoard)[cur->pos[0]-'A'][cur->pos[1]-'1'] deference so now you have a chessboard which you then index as if it was an array .  This makes no sense.

Spellcheck.  It's "Remove" not "Remuve".  Be consistent with naming (lower case first letter) so removeRepeatingPos()

Things will be easier if you follow common naming conventions. Types begin with an uppercase letter, variables begin with a lowercase letter.
